# Formatting data using MVC design

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller, core-location

I have a TableViewController and model class `TripInfo`. When the cell accessory view is tapped, I'd like to return the address of the current location to the cell's textfield. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this cleanly abiding by the MVC pattern.

Here's what I have so far:

1.TableViewController implementation: accessory view is tapped, `locationManager` starts updating
2.TableViewController implementation:`locationManager` didUpdateLocation method is called and sets the current to the model object property `self.tripInfo.location`

Now I need to convert this location into a physical address. I was going to put this code in a model class method that returns an address as a string, for example:

```
- (NSString *)createAddressStringFromLocation: (CLLocation *)location
{

    __block NSString *locationAddress = @"";

    CLGeocoder *gecoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [gecoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks lastObject];

        locationAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary(placemark.addressDictionary, NO)];
    }];

    return locationAddress;
}
```

Then in cellForRow:

```
cell.textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.tripInfo createAddressStringFromLocation:self.tripInfo.fromLocation]];
```

Is this bad design to have cellForRow basically wait for this method to complete in my model class?

Comment: `reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler` returns immediately, so this code shouldn't even work in the first place (it's run asynchronously... if the results are already cached, it may execute synchronously, but certainly not in the general case, since it's advertised as async).

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain further?

Comment: Ok I understand now. Am I better off putting the reverse geocode implementation in the tableViewController and set the outputted string as a `tripInfo` property?